# presentingViewController not working

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call a method on the presenting ViewController when I dismiss a popup ViewController. I start the Popup from the 'MainViewController' like this: (With help of EzPopup Library, but I think that shouldn't matter here)

```
@IBAction func onStartWorkout(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let startWorkoutVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent") as! StartWorkout_ViewController

    let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: startWorkoutVC, popupWidth: 300, popupHeight: 500)
    popupVC.cornerRadius = 10

    present(popupVC, animated: true)
}
```

then when I dismiss the Popup I do this:

```
func dissmissPopup()  {
    if let presenter = presentingViewController as? MainViewController {
        presenter.startWorkout(index: 0, isSNR: true)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But the method won't be called. How does presentingViewController work and why doesn't my reference to MainViewController work?

Comment: What class is this `dissmissPopup` method in?

Comment: because **presentingViewController** is nil

Comment: @Popmedic `presentingViewController` is a property of `UIViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy I is on 'StartWorkout_ViewController' as you assumed

Comment: @Sh_Khan I know its nil, the question is why is it nil and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `dissmissPopup` is in your `StartWorkout_ViewController` class then `presentingViewController` will be `nil` because you are not presenting `StartWorkout_ViewController`, you are presenting `PopupViewController`. The `presentingViewController` of `PopupViewController` should be your `MainViewController`.

Depending on how `PopupViewController` is written, you should be able to get what you need by accessing `parent` (giving you the `PopupViewController`, and then accessing its `presentingViewController`.

```
func dissmissPopup()  {
    if let presenter = parent?.presentingViewController as? MainViewController {
        presenter.startWorkout(index: 0, isSNR: true)
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now, having said all of that, don't do this. It's a poor, fragile design. You are hardcoding into `StartWorkout_ViewController` the knowledge that `MainViewController` needs some specific method called.

The proper solution is to define a protocol and a delegate. Then `StartWorkout_ViewController` simply calls the protocol method on its delegate (not caring who it really is). And `MainViewController` sets itself as `StartWorkout_ViewController`'s delegate and implements the protocol's methods.

This approach eliminates the need for `StartWorkout_ViewController` to know who presented it or how. It eliminates the need for `StartWorkout_ViewController` to know to specifically call a method named `startWorkout`. It also allows other classes to present `MainViewController` and do whatever it needs when it is dismissed without further hardcoded changes to `MainViewController`.

Here's a rough outline of implementing this with a protocol and delegate:

StartWorkout_ViewController.swift:

```
protocol StartWorkoutDelegate: class {
    func complete() // add any necessary parameters
}

class StartWorkout_ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: StartWorkoutDelegate?

    func dissmissPopup()  {
        delegate?.complete() // add any necessary parameters

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

MainViewController.swift:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, StartWorkoutDelegate {
    @IBAction func onStartWorkout(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let startWorkoutVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent") as! StartWorkout_ViewController
        startWorkoutVC.delegate = self

        let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: startWorkoutVC, popupWidth: 300, popupHeight: 500)
        popupVC.cornerRadius = 10

        present(popupVC, animated: true)
    }

    func complete() {
        startWorkout() // add any necessary parameters
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! The first way with 'parent?.presentingViewController' does not work. But I would also rather to the 2nd way. Could you please provide a little code example? I´m new to swift (coming from java), I know what protocols are but I don't understand what you mean by "calls a protocol method from its delegate".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the idea.